# Is it possible to create "Glossary Categories" in Purview as was possible in Apache Atlas?

Tags: azure, glossary, azure-purview

In Atlas, it was possible to create a hierarchy of categories and subcategories in the Glossary to partition all the Business Terms.

Is there any way to create similar categories/sub-categories in Purview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately,  it is not possible to create “Glossary Categories” in Purview as was possible in Apache Atlas.

Here is an existing feature request submitted by a user. Please feel free to upvote and/or comment if you haven't already, which would help to increase the priority of feature request suggestion.

Feature request thread link: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/932437-azure-purview/suggestions/42593734-hierarchical-organisation-of-terms-in-business-glo